# Очередной вопрос про то как изменить url через htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Есть урл вида : /ru/nashi-uslugi/zheleznodorozhnye-perevozki.html. 
С него отправляется post запрос в котором передаются 2 параметра start = "Москва" и end="Саратов". url На который это отправляется /ru/mypsevdonim.html.

Нужно привести его в виду /ru/nashi-uslugi/moskva/saratov

Осознаю как классно это звучит, но примерно это попросили сделать меня. Если кто - то может помочь - большущее спасибо ибо у меня за 2 дня ничего не вышло.

Comment: можете описать подробнее, как отправляется форма, на каком фреймворке/cms это происходит, привести пример кода,того что есть.

Comment: `moskva/saratov` это транслит городов из `start/end` ? чисто хтаксесом вы такое не сделаете.